# css background image works locally but not remotely

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following css in my `application.css.scss` file

```
html {
    background: url("model-bg.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

It works fine locally but when I push it to heroku the image doesn't load.

The generated css looks like this:

```
html {
    background: url(../assets/model-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

I can't access the file via the browser. And `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Can you access the file via a browser? ../assets/model-bg.jpg should be accesible using it's url, did you compile your assets after deploy?

Comment: ah no I can't - I'll try that.

Comment: hmm. doesn't work $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the specific helper for that purpose and then recompiling your assets:

```
background: image-url("model-bg.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
```

and move your image to `/app/assets/images`.